# Application Loader gives a wrong error

Tags: iphone

I am trying to upload a universal binary of my app using Application Loader. I have an Icon.png file which is sized 57 x 57. When I upload the binary, Application Loader gives me an error saying that the size is incorrect and that it should be 72 x 72. The iOS reference library has an article (QA1686) that says the size of this file should be 57 x 57.

Answer (score 2):

You probably built your application as iPad app (or iPhone+iPad app). 72x72 is the iPad icon size.